# Kotlin a list of random distinct numbers

Tags: list, kotlin

I am creating a list of random numbers using the following approach

```
val randomList = List(4) { Random.nextInt(0, 100) }
```

However, this approach doesn't work as I want to avoid repetitions

Answer (score 18):

One way is to shuffle a [Range](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/ranges.html) and take as many items as you want:

```
val randomList = (0..99).shuffled().take(4)
```

This is not so efficient if the range is big and you only need just a few numbers.
In this case it's better to use a [Set](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-set/index.html) like this:

```
val s: MutableSet<Int> = mutableSetOf()
while (s.size < 4) { s.add((0..99).random()) }
val randomList = s.toList()
```

Answer (score 0):

Create:

```
 val list = (0 until 100).toMutableList()  
    val randList = mutableListOf<Int>()
    
    for (i in 0 until 4) {
        val uniqueRand = list.random()
        randList.add(uniqueRand)
        list.remove(uniqueRand)
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

One line approach to get a list of `n` distinct random elements. `Random` is not limited in any way.

```
val list = mutableSetOf<Int>().let { while (it.size() < n) it += Random.nextInt(0, 100) }.toList()
```