# How do you choose each time a new element from an array?

Tags: kotlin

How do you choose each time a new element from an array?
I need when I click on the button, one adapter is selected at a time in the order and then it comes back in the selection again
This is my code in a nutshell:

```
      var adp1: adpter1
  var adp2: adpter2
  var adp3: adpter3
  var adp4: adpter4
  var adp5: adpter5
  var adp6: adpter6
  val ar0 arrayListOf(adp1, adp2, adp3, adp4, adp5, adp6) 
recyclerView.adapter = ar0
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"choose a new element"*? Do you mean a random one?

Comment: Yes. And without repetition

Comment: Have you done any research at all? There are plenty of questions that cover this. If you have researched, then what have you tried already? Why didn't it work, etc.?

Comment: var lastItem = -1

   fun getRandomItemFromList(): Int {
        val randomValue = java.util.Random().nextInt(ar0.size)
        return if (randomValue != lastItem) {
            lastItem = randomValue
            randomValue
        } else {
            getRandomItemFromList()
        }

    }

rec1.adapter = ar0.get(getRandomItemFromList()

Comment: Elements can be duplicated in it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kotlin a list of random distinct numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55212248/kotlin-a-list-of-random-distinct-numbers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments you want to pick one random element from the array, without repetition. The understanding of "without repetition" could be different for each of us, so I am going to assume you want to pick a random element from the list as long as no equal value has already been selected before. Example: if the code has already selected value "one" then you don't want the code to pick "one" anymore (even if the original list contains multiple instances of "one").

I believe the best way to do this is to use a combination of [`distinct()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/distinct.html) (to remove duplicates) and [`shuffled()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/shuffled.html) (to shuffle the collection), like this:

```
val data = listOf("one", "two", "three", "one", "two", "four")
val shuffledUniqueData = data.distinct().shuffled()

// do something with shuffledUniqueData. In this case just print the content
println(shuffledUniqueData.joinToString(","))
```

That code produces a different output every time it is executed. For example:

```
one,three,two,four
one,four,three,two
two,three,one,four
...
```